# Does each field update in Approval Processes cause a trigger to fire for each update, or does it act in bulk?

Tags: trigger, approval-process, approval-step, approve-action

We have a quite bit of activity that acts on update of an Object which causes UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors with subsequent transactions within a 2 minute time period. Hence, I'm trying to minimalize DML wherever I can. My question is in an Approval Process, does each individual Field Update per "action" (i.e. an Initial Submission Action) fire a separate trigger on the same object per update or does this occur in bulk? I'm aware that triggers run, but wondering if field updates are consolidated before the trigger fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the updated Order of Execution diagram from Salesforce, the Workflow Field Updates that an Approval Process runs should all be completed at the same time. That means that before and after update triggers should be fired again (and only one more time) for the all of the Approval Process updates.

Reference: https://architect.salesforce.com/1/asset/immutable/s/2d349e8/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png